# System crashes with skimage.transform.resize

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, scikit-image

My system crashes and reboots when I try to resize a numpy array of shape (35887,48,48) to (35887,100,100) using

```py
arr = skimage.transform.resize(arr,(35887,100,100))
```

Comment: *"...  crashes and reboots..."*  Wow.  What is your system?  How much memory do you have?

Comment: How much memory is in your system? If `arr` is floating point the resized array will take about 3GB.  It seems unlikely that's enough to cause your system to run out of memory, but it could be depending on what `skimage.transform.resize` does.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser i3 4150, 8 GB

Comment: What is the operating system? (Windows, Mac OSX, Linux, something else?)

Comment: @Warren Weckesser  Windows. The task manager displays 100% memory and disk usage before crashing.

Comment: One more question: which version of `scikit-image` are you using?  You can check with `import skimage; print(skimage.__version__)`.  I suspect this is a problem with skimage not handling an out-of-memory condition correctly.  If so, it is a bug in skimage and should be reported at https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser    0.14.2

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser   updated to version 0.15. It's still happening.

Comment: What is the the dtype of arr?

Comment: @tstanisl the dtype is int

Comment: @Neeraj Kumar; The int is quite strange for images. Usually float32 (for dynamic range) or uint8 (for compactness) are used.

Answer (score 0):

This fails because you resize a 3D array rather than a bunch of 2D arrays.
The library does interpolation along the first dimension. It means that separate images are mixed.

Try to resize each image separately in the loop.

```
outarr = np.array([skimage.transform.resize(ent, (100,100)) for ent in arr])
```

However, I strongly recommend to use opencv because:

- it is far faster
- does not convert images to double
- it allows to pass output buffer

Just preallocate memory before resizing and run the loop.

Code:

```
import cv2
outarr = np.empty((arr.shape[0], 100,100), dtype=arr.dtype) # create buffer
for src, dst in zip(arr, outarr):
    cv2.resize(src, dsize=dst.shape, dst=dst)
```

It should resize all images in circa 1 sec. Good luck!

Comment: Trying to resize each image separately in a loop also crashes my system. But I will give OpenCV a try :)

Comment: Consider converting arr to np.uin8. It will greatly reduce memory consumption (4 times in comparison to int).

Comment: It is still crashes.

Comment: Did you try to convert input array (arr) to uint8 before resizing?

Comment: Yes tstanisl , that's what I was saying.

Comment: (35887,48,48) of unit8 consumes 72MiB, after resizing it will be 342+78=420 MiB. This is little for today standards. It must be something else what crashes your system.

Comment: Yes, and I can't figure out what. All I see is the memory consumption jumping to 7.9 GBs in a few seconds and then everything freezes forever.